# How to user TINT text color in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am starting off with Ionic 4 and have soem trouble with the colors.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/basics

So I can do

```
<span color="primary">TEXT</span>
```

and the text will be blue. But in the documentation there are two other types of primary. Shade and Tint. How can I make my text primary tint?

Comment: This is still not possible, I guess. Any chance we can get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to set specific variation of a color, such as tint, do not set the color property in the ion-text element and define a custom class.

*your.page.html*

```
<ion-text class="my-class">
   <h1>text</h1>
</ion-text>
```

*your.page.scss*

```
.my-class {
  color: var(--ion-color-primary-tint);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ionic 4 theme color can be found in `theme > variables.scss`

The Ionic CSS variables are placed inside the :root.

```
:root {
  --ion-color-primary: #3880ff;
  --ion-color-primary-rgb: 218,93,88;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-primary-shade: #3171e0;
  --ion-color-primary-tint: #4c8dff;

...
}
```

### USAGE

On an element with takes the `color` tag.

```
<div color="primary"></div>
<div color="primary-shade"></div>
<div color="primary-tint"></div>
```

On a given `class` using the Ionic custom color properties.

```
.class{
  color: var(--ion-color-primary);
}
.class{
  color: var(--ion-color-primary-shade);
}
.class{
  color: var(--ion-color-tint);
}
```

Comment: Using the -tint & -shade on the color attribute directly on the element doesn't seem work. When the any of the layer colors are used, ionic doesn't add the ion-color-primary class to the element.
Even modifying the class in chrome inspector to ion-color-primary-tint doesn't apply it.